# Eureka client on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I have a microservices cluster run under Kubernetes. I want to get access to Eureka instance from Eureka, but everything is behind cluster private network. How to register eureka.instance.serviceUrl as defined in Kubernetes service? or better - proxy to pod? So that I can directly access instance through Eureka api for debugging purpose.